# Creating model based on file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection

I have a question, is it possible and how to create model based on my file? For example -> I created application.properties file where I have 2 properties like:
`name.type: STRING` and `name.value: JOHN`. 
What I want to do is creating an object based on it which is like a simple pojo which has properties which I have already defined. Of course I would like to easily change my file and add another field which could be easily converted just as this one. I have already read sth about reflection API in Java, however I am still unable to come up with an idea how to do it. Do you know any solutions to my problem?

Comment: This sounds like a job for your build tool (i.e. a Maven plugin), not your language (Java) or framework (Spring Boot).

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to "tell" Maven to create simple POJO which i have to use in my program. And I have never heard of anyone doing such things with maven.

Comment: It always fascinates me, how the term “POJO” has been perverted since its creation. There is only one way to create a POJO: 1) Open an editor, 2) write Java code. Otherwise, it’s not a POJO.